# CSS3 Unable to reverse animation

Tags: css, animation, reverse

I've got a problem.

I want to play a CSS animation and then let the user revert it by clicking a button.
Since in my future project there will be a lot of animations like this I didn't want to make the keyframes for forward animation and the ones for the backward animation.

Since it exists I want to use the "animation-direction: reverse" property but I'm encountering a prblem:
after I've played the animation with direction "normal" it seems I can't play it animore with the "reverse" property.

```
.expand-bl {
    animation: expand-bl-kf 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-direction: normal;
}
.collapse-bl {
    animation: expand-bl-kf 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-direction: reverse;
}
```

Why is that?
Does anyone know a workaround this?

Here is a fiddle with the issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/armoxo1q/1/

**EDIT:**

I've found this article:
https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/

It says to remove and append the element again with jquery or (in the comments) to use a setTimeout.
From a processing point of view I like the setTimeout better because the browser doesn't have to detatch and reappend a node 
while I like the remove/append mode from an aesthetic point of view because with setTimeout you can see a little flash where the #container DIV is collapsed and then it animates

I've added these methods to my fiddle

Comment: Seems this is still an issue in 2022... I can't get my `keyframe` animations to reverse either. I just went ahead & duplicated the logic & explicitly created reverse animations by flipping the `to` and `from`. In my case there aren't that many but pity it doesn't work out of the box

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `animation-iteration-count` is `1` by default, and your animation has already done that iteration.

Therefore, you can increase it to `2`:

```css
.collapse-bl {
    animation: expand-bl-kf 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-direction: reverse;
    animation-iteration-count: 2;
}
```

```js
document.getElementById("container").className = "expand-bl";

document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("animationend", function (e) {
  console.log(e)
  if (e.animationName === "expand-bl-kf" && e.target.className === "expand-bl") document.getElementById("close").style.display = "block";
  else if (e.animationName === "expand-bl-kf" && e.target.className === "collapse-bl") document.getElementById("close").style.display = "none";
});

document.getElementById("close").addEventListener("click", function () {
  document.getElementById("container").className = "collapse-bl";
});
```

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#close {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 999;
}
#stage {
  width:600px;
  height:600px;
  background-color: pink;
}
#container {
  width:300px;
  height:250px;
  background-color: orange;
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  top: 0px;
}
.expand-bl {
  animation: expand-bl-kf 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-direction: normal;
}
.collapse-bl {
  animation: expand-bl-kf 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-direction: reverse;
  animation-iteration-count: 2;
}
@keyframes expand-bl-kf {
  from {
    width:300px;
    height:250px;
    left: 300px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  to {
    width:600px;
    height:600px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="close">close</button>
<div id="stage">
  <div id="container" class="container"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for anwsering. But if I set the iteration to 2 on the expansion I will get the expansion animation twice and then I will have the same problem on the collapsing, if I set it to the collapsing like in your snippet I can't see any difference =/.